# Header with TabNavigation React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

What is the best way to have a header with the page title with a tab navigator with react native? I know there is a way to wrap you TabNavigator inside of StackNavigator, but I do not understand how to do this with different components in different classes...

This is what I am doing to set up the TabNavigator:

Inside App.js:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Activity: Activity,
  Front: Front
},
{
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      let iconName;
      if (routeName === 'Activity') {
        iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
      } else if (routeName === 'Front') {
        iconName = `ios-cog`;
      }
      return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={horizontal ? 20 : 25} color={tintColor} />;
  },
}),
tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: 'tomato',
  inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
},
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each tab can be a StackNavigator, for example:

```
const activityStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Activity: {
    screen: Activity,
    navigationOption: {
      headerTitle: 'Some title...'
    }
  }
})
```

And then in your TabNavigator just use the StackNavigator you just created as a screen:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Activity: activityStackNavigator,
    Front: Front
  },
  ...
}
```

Here's some [read](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab) from the React-Navigation docs.