# Add a header to BottomTabNavigator in v.5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I've recently started coding in React Native and cannot find a good way to add a header to my views. I'm using `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()` and therefor I cannot add a `createStackNavigator()`.

So my question is quite simple. How can I add a header to React Native using `BottomTabNavigator`?

```
const MaterialBottomTab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MaterialBottomTab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        activeColor="white"
        shifting={true}
        barStyle={styles.bottomBarStyle}
      >
        <MaterialBottomTab.Screen 
          name="Home" 
          component={Home}  
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialIcons name="home" color={color} size={25}/>
            )
          }}
        />
        <MaterialBottomTab.Screen 
          name="History" 
          component={History}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "History",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialIcons name="history" color={color} size={25}/>
            )
          }} 
        />
        <MaterialBottomTab.Screen 
          name="New"
          component={AddFood} 
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "New",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialIcons name="add" color={color} size={25}/>
            )
          }}
        />
      </MaterialBottomTab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Header with TabNavigation React Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053123/header-with-tabnavigation-react-navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn all your screens for each tab into stack navigators, they will have the header. Or you can create a custom header component that you put in each of those screens without converting them into stacks.

Docs here : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Comment: So, let's say I have 2 functions. "Home()" and "App()". Which one should I use "export default" on? Or how else can I make sure the function is called?

Comment: either you put them in separate files and use `export default` or you can also drop the default and just export multiple from the same file.

Comment: for example if you do `export function App()` and `export function Home()` you would just do `import { App, Home } from /filepath` when you want to import

Comment: Ohhhh, makes sense! I'll check this out! :)

Comment: depending on your file structure you can keep them in one file or multiple. I usually tend to keep components/navigators in their own files and `export default`

Comment: Thanks.

Another quick question. Is a StackNavigator required in order to navigate to other pages? In the first place I skipped that part because I already had a "BottomTabBar" which I thought would do the job.

Comment: It is not required, you will still be able to navigate between the tabs. the stack navigator will mostly be useful if you want to navigate between screens on that tab itself

Comment: Ah, thats what I meant. It is required if I want to navigate between screens. :)
Damn, this language is confused so far. I've to study it harder